# How to read a chart winapi c#

Tags: c#, winapi, charts

i have used this code to get the handle of a child window in the chart,

```
    [DllImport("user32")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr i);
    public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
    {
        List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
        GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
        try
        {
            EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
            EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                listHandle.Free();
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
    {
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
        List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
        }
        list.Add(handle);

        return true;
    }


    public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr parameter);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (Process Proces in Process.GetProcesses())
        {             

                IntPtr lastWindowHandle = GetWindow(Proces.MainWindowHandle, (uint)GetWindow_Cmd.GW_HWNDNEXT);
                GetChildWindows(Proces.MainWindowHandle);

        }
    }
```

i want to get the open high low close of candles from the chart but i dont know how to read that.I have used this code to read get the data from the chart but it is returning empty string.

```
    public object GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        functions.StrData = "";
        object obj2 = "";
        if (hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            return "";
        }
        functions.SendMessage(hWnd, 0x111, (IntPtr)0x81eb, IntPtr.Zero);
        functions.StrData = functions.StrData + Clipboard.GetText();
        functions.SendMessage(hWnd, 0x307, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        return obj2;
    }
```

I have also used .Net Object Spy to know what the handle is,here is the picture of it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNtvc.jpg

I just want to read the highlighted windows and get the candles data whose handle is 4982638.Hope you all understood my question,thanks in advance..

Comment: Image recognition (is what you are looking for) is very broad and non-trivial area... It likely easier to get data you are looking for more direct way than capturing image and writing code to convert it back into tabular data of some form... (Also in such simple case you may be able to write recognition code by hand rather than relying on libraries...).

Comment: its totally different what you are telling me to do.the candle contains open high low close data.I cant get the data by using image recognition.i want to read the data of the candle.not the shape

Comment: Not sure what exactly your are looking to find help with on SO. It looks like you *know* that program you trying to scrape data from exposes information you are looking for in readable for via some API. In this case it would be more productive to ask a question about using/calling that API (preferably you'd need link to documentation in addition)... If you just *believe* that any image in any window have very well structured data easily available you are in for big disappointment - image in a window is just an image.

Comment: ok.so can u tell me how to scrap that data ?because when i tried the upper method it gave me a null value.am i going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Are you trying to get the handle to an Office document's chart? I don't think those are separate window handles...

Comment: no they are fixed in that window itself